# How does the Disengage action interact with opportunity attacks when invisible?

Tags: dnd-5e, opportunity-attack, invisibility

I've got an encounter planned involving several creatures who were modified by magic to be able to camouflage themselves to such an extent that the only time they are visible is that instant when they attack a player (think active camo from the Halo series). I've read up on rules for attacking from stealth and attacking a 'hidden' enemy, but I was unable to find anything about how disengaging would go into it.

Currently I plan on having those creatures that leave without using a disengage action provide an opportunity attack from the nearby players albeit with disadvantage due to the camouflage. Would this be an accurate ruling, or would it be more correct to say that, since they are exceptionally hidden, the players would be unable to do an attack of opportunity?

Comment: Related: [When you cast invisibility on your turn, and walk away from 2 enemies, do they get an attack of opportunity?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/102594)

Comment: Your last sentence includes the phrase "exceptionally hidden" to describe the camouflage's effect. This leads me to believe that you might be conflating merely invisible/unseen with hidden, which are two different things in 5E. You may wish to review other answers on this site to familiarize yourself with the difference.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Opportunity Attacks Depend on Sight

As per the [basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#OpportunityAttacks):

> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature that **you can see** moves out of your reach.

If the character can see the enemy, they can use their reaction to make an opportunity attack.

If they cannot see the enemy, they cannot take an opportunity attack.

### Use Ready Action to Attack Briefly Visible Enemy

This assumes that attacking renders the enemy visible, and it then gets some sort of free action to become invisible again.  In this case, a character could use the ready action to strike as soon as the enemy become visible.  However, that means characters with extra attack won't get to use that feature.

Comment: I think the answer might be worth expanding slightly to note that though the players won't get to make opportunity attacks, they *could* use the Ready action on their turns to prepare an attack the instant such a creature appears next to them, so there is a way they can use their reactions to get attacks against these creatures.

Comment: Extra attack also won't work.

Comment: Since in this case the players are the ones making the OAs you may want to say Extra Attack. Multi-attack is a monster ability. It also might be good to *explicitly* say that because OAs can depend on sight, there is no reason for the monsters in the question to disengage. Just to fully close the loop on the question.

Comment: Also worth noting that simply being invisible won't stop players from attacking - the creature would have to take the *hide* action and beat the PCs perception for that.